# Triggering an Azure Pipeline release package deployment via HTTP API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, terraform, azure-web-app-service

I have a Terraform script that spins up an App Service. This script is triggered via HTTP get request.

Then I have a package within Azure DevOps pipeline that I currently deploy manually once the App Service has been created.

My question is: is there a way to chain these two together, is there some sort of API / HTTP Trigger I could use to deploy an already existing package to my newly created App Service? I could not find anything of the sort after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can do it via Logic Apps https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/step-by-step-trigger-azure-pipeline-when-task-item-lahiri-cristofori

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).